# Как закрыть от внешнего мира node.js приложение в инфраструктуре на docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Пробую организовать инфраструктуру приложения с docker-compose.
Вот исходный код:

server.js

```
const fastify = require('fastify');

const app = fastify();

app.get('/', (_req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello world!');
});

app.listen({port: 3333, host: '0.0.0.0'}, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.info(`fastify server listening...`);
});
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
   mysql:
     image: mysql
     ...
     ports:
       - 3306:3306

  webserver:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
    networks:
      - app-network

  nodejs:
    build: ./node
    container_name: nodejs
    hostname: nodejs
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - ./node:/node_app/
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    networks:
      - app-network    

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nodejs:3333;
    }

}

server {
    listen 3333;
    listen [::]:3333;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        return 404;
    }

}
```

запускаю docker-compose up,
обращаюсь из браузера на `http://localhost` получаю вижу 'Hello world!'.
Но и на `http://localhost:3333` так же вижу 'Hello world!'.

Как мне закрыть от внешнего мира нодовское приложение?

А еще получается у меня и база светит наружу.
С одной стороны это хорошо, т.к. при локальной разработке я могу использовать MySQL Workbench, с другой на проде ее бы надо закрыть.

Как правильно организовать видимость контейнеров при разработке и на проде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно убрать port из docker-compose, эта настройка как раз и открывает порты наружу, а внутри сети app-network (для других контейнеров) они буду доступны в любом случае. Это достаточно легко проверить убрав порты и подключившись "левым" контейнером к сети, сервер будет доступен.

Comment: Круто! я немного по другому себе представлял себе работу этих портов. спасибо)

Comment: а есть удобный способ при разработке порт открыть а на проде скрыть? ну например тот же 3306

Comment: использовать разные docker-compose файлы, для прода и дева